# pg_dump connection to database "db_name" failed: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to take the pg_dump of a database from my local system by running the following command in my terminal:

```
mypc@mypc:~$  pg_dump -U postgres existing_db_name > dbexport.sql
```

And I am getting this following error.

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "db_name" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

It is not even prompting for password.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the password as an environment variable `PGPASSWORD`. You can fire this off as a single command eg.

```
 PGPASSWORD="password" pg_dump -U postgres existing_db_name > dbexport.sql
```

Or you can adjust your `hba.conf` file and set the user postgres to trust on local connections. From the error its likely set to peer.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Or you can create a .pass file
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html